# pg_restore restore FK constraints with explicit --table argument

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I started using the `-t` argument of pg_restore to only restore some tables, which has worked well for read-only workflows.

The problem is that the `-t` seems to not restore the FK constraints nor sequences applied to the table/column.

Regarding the former (sequence), it seems that the tables restored with `-t` which had an `id` column with a modifier of `not null default nextval('report_id_seq'::regclass)` was restored with just `not null`, so the sequence isn't applied, which is an obvious.

Is there a way to use `pg_restore` with explicit tables using `-t` that also restore foreign-key constraints and sequences?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to restore all things that are *not* data. So try `-s`, from `man pg_restore`

```
-s
--schema-only
    Restore only the schema (data definitions), not data, to the extent
    that schema entries are present in the archive.

    This option is the inverse of --data-only. It is similar to, but
    for historical reasons not identical to, specifying
    --section=pre-data --section=post-data.

    (Do not confuse this with the --schema option, which uses the word
    “schema” in a different meaning.)
```

Note that `schema` is everything. Foreign key constraints mean you may not be able to load just the data for a table. From `pg_dump`

> when -t is specified, pg_dump makes no attempt to dump any other database objects that the selected table(s) might depend upon. Therefore, there is no guarantee that the results of a specific-table dump can be successfully restored by themselves into a clean database.

So if you've got a clean database, and you try to restore with `-t` you're potentially attempting to insert data the conflicts keys and constraints specified in the schema `-s`.

Comment: If I first run the command with `-s`, and then run it with `-t` to get the data, I get a lot of errors violating the FK constraints.

Comment: Sure you do -- to be expected. If you need the data too, you need the insertion order that pg_restore and pg_dump provides. How else could it possibly work... If table `foo` references `bar`. `bar` has to be loaded first. If you `-t foo` later, and `bar` isn't loaded -- what do want to happen?

Comment: Right, I hear that edge case. In what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to exclude some tables that don't have any other tables referencing to them as FK.